# PHP - Display variables from array

Tags: php, arrays

I've very new to arrays and this is just beyond my understanding. How can I get the data out of this array and display it in an echo. I know this is an easy one! Thanks in advance!
Here is the var_dump

```
array(2) { [0]=>  string(10) "John Smith" [1]=>  string(10) "Smithville" }
```

and code below

```
$string = "John Smith Smithville";
$townlist = array("smithville", "janeville", "placeville");

function stringSeperation($string, $list)
{
    $result = array();

    foreach($list as $item)
    {
        $pos = strrpos(strtolower($string), strtolower($item));
        if($pos !== false)
        {
            $result = array(trim(substr($string, 0, $pos)), trim(substr($string, $pos)));
            break;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

var_dump(stringSeperation($string, $townlist));
```

echo name

echo town

Regards,
-Dan

Answer (score 3):

```
$result = stringSeperation($string, $townlist);

echo $result[0]; // prints the name
echo $result[1]; // prints the town
```

or

```
foreach($result as $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

[Learn more about arrays.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Note: For linebreaks, you should either use `PHP_EOL` or `<br />` depending on whether you want to generate HTML or not.

Answer (score 2):

```
$strs = stringSeperation($string, $townlist);
echo $strs[0] . "\n";
echo $strs[1] . "\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$data = stringSeperation($string, $townlist);

$name = $data[0];
$town = $data[1];

echo $name;
echo $town;
```

Answer (score 1):

`echo arrayName[i];` where `i` is the index of the array you wish to output.

So in your case, `echo $result[0];` will output name, `echo $result[1];` will output town.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply echo an element of the array if you know the key by doing this

`echo $townlist[0]; //this will echo smithville`

If you want to echo the whole array do this

```
$count = count($townlist)

for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
    echo $townlist[$i];
}
```

this will output

```
smithville
janeville
placeville
```

hope that helps you out!

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = count($result);

for($counter = 0;$counter<$count;$counter++)
{
    echo $result[$counter];
}
```

or

```
foreach($result as $value) 
{
    echo $value;
}
```